# How to integrate Google Drive with Picasso on Android?

Tags: android, caching, picasso, google-drive-android-api

I'm writing an app which stores images in Google Drive and I'd like to display a gallery of those (`GridView`). To be more performant (i.e. async) I'd like to integrate this with `Picasso`. But the `Picasso.load(String)` is just an alias to `load(Uri.parse(path))`, and I don't have a `Uri` because the images are loaded like this (simplified and with undisclosed utility methods):

```
public static Bitmap getBitmap(DriveId id) {
    GoogleApiClient client = ApiClientAsyncTask.createConnectedClient(App.getAppContext());
    DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(client, id);
    Metadata meta = sync(file.getMetadata(client));
    Contents contents = sync(file.openContents(client, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null));
    InputStream imageStream = contents.getInputStream();
    try {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
    } finally {
        IOTools.ignorantClose(imageStream);
        sync(file.discardContents(client, contents));
    }
}
```

Is there any other similar library maybe supporting integration of arbitrary inputs (String/Object)?

Of course I'd like to use the full support of caching (network (the above method), disk, memory) in Picasso.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? The only solution I could think of involves a lot of rewrite of the caching process. Drive does provide a metadata link for getWebContentLink, but this does not seem to work with Picasso, given that Picasso does not have proper authentication.

Comment: I converted to bumptech Glide, it's a more generic tool, with similar, but extremely flexible API. Picasso 2.5.0 has a new `RequestHandler` which may be able to achieve what we want. (It's possible we need to fake an URL like: "driveId://cafebabe123")

Comment: Care to show an example of how you are using Glide to load the image from drive? I can see that it has many more "load()" calls than Picasso offers, including one for a byte array. Is that the one you are using?

Comment: I was wrong, that URL hacking was required to try to send the request through Picasso, added an answer for Glide.

Answer (score 8):

The version of Picasso at the time didn't support what I wanted so I went to use [Glide 3](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). Here's what I managed to put together.
*I didn't test it yet, I pieced it together from history, because I removed this support from my app, it was an overkill; however it was working when the functionality was still present.*

in `ConnectionCallbacks.onConnected`:

```
Glide.get(getContext()).register(DriveId.class, InputStream.class, new DriveIdModelLoader.Factory(mClient));
```

in `ConnectionCallbacks.onConnectionSuspended`:

```
Glide.get(getContext()).unregister(DriveId.class, InputStream.class);
```

in list `Adapter`:

```
String driveString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
DriveId driveId = DriveId.decodeFromString(driveString);
Glide.with(this)
     .from(DriveId.class)
     .load(driveId)
     .into(imageView);
```

Glide glue:

```
import java.io.*;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;

import com.bumptech.glide.load.data.DataFetcher;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.model.*;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.model.stream.StreamModelLoader;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveId;

public class DriveIdModelLoader implements StreamModelLoader<DriveId> {
    private final GoogleApiClient client;

    public DriveIdModelLoader(GoogleApiClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public DataFetcher<InputStream> getResourceFetcher(DriveId model, int width, int height) {
        return new DriveIdDataFetcher(client, model);
    }

    public static class Factory implements ModelLoaderFactory<DriveId, InputStream> {
        private final GoogleApiClient client;

        public Factory(GoogleApiClient client) {
            this.client = client;
        }

        public ModelLoader<DriveId, InputStream> build(Context context, GenericLoaderFactory factories) {
            return new DriveIdModelLoader(client);
        }

        public void teardown() {
            client.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Drive related Glide logic:

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.slf4j.*;

import com.bumptech.glide.Priority;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.data.DataFetcher;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.*;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.*;

public class DriveIdDataFetcher implements DataFetcher<InputStream> {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DriveIdDataFetcher.class);

    private final GoogleApiClient client;
    private final DriveId driveId;

    private boolean cancelled = false;

    private DriveFile file;
    private Contents contents;

    public DriveIdDataFetcher(GoogleApiClient client, DriveId driveId) {
        this.client = client;
        this.driveId = driveId;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return driveId.encodeToString();
    }

    public InputStream loadData(Priority priority) {
        if (cancelled) return null;
        if (client == null) {
            LOG.warn("No connected client received, giving custom error image");
            return null;
        }
        file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(client, driveId);
        if (cancelled) return null;
        contents = sync(file.openContents(client, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)).getContents();
        if (cancelled) return null;
        return contents.getInputStream();
    }

    public void cancel() {
        cancelled = true;
        if (contents != null) {
            file.discardContents(client, contents);
        }
    }

    public void cleanup() {
        if (contents != null) {
            sync(file.discardContents(client, contents));
        }
    }

    private static <T extends Result> void assertSuccess(T result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(result.getStatus().toString());
        }
    }

    private static <T extends Result> T sync(PendingResult<T> pending) {
        T result = pending.await();
        assertSuccess(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can download an image from Google Drive in this way:

```
    //this is the original Google Drive link to the image
    String s="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9nFwumYtUw9Q05WNlhlM2lqNzQ/view?usp=sharing";

    //you have to get the part of the link 0B9nFwumYtUw9Q05WNlhlM2lqNzQ
    String[] p=s.split("/");
    //Create the new image link
    String imageLink="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="+p[5];
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Picasso.with(YourActivity.this).load(imageLink).into(imageView);
```

that is all

Comment: I remember trying something like that, but it doesn't work for private files. You need to be authenticated, which means using the play services API, so you need complex Url handling.

Comment: Fantastic solution